# Pascal(ошибка времени выполнения входная строка имела неверный формат)

Tags: pascal

В программе работает все, кроме удаления записи из файла

Собственно сама ошибка:

> строка (254) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

В строке 254 находится `(readln(menu);)`

```
  program Telophonia;

type
  abonent = record
    number:   string[10];                //Номер телефона
    FIO:      string[40];                //ФИО абонента
    adres: record               //Адрес абонента в виде другой записи состоящий из:
    street: string[20];                            //Улица
    house:  string[20];                            //Дом
    flat:   string[20];                            //Квартира
    end;
    date:     string[10];                   //Дата подключения абонента
  end;

var
  abonents: file of abonent;             //Файл содержащий записи об абонентах
  x, t: abonent;                        //Вспомогательная переменная типа записи об абонентах
  menu, ind, cnt: integer;              //Вспомогательные переменные для меню, индексации и счетчика записей в некоторых процедурах
  yn: char;                             //Переменная y/n ответов
  filename: string[25];                 //Имя файла, задаваемое пользователем
  nmbr: string[10];                     //Вспомогательная переменная для номера абонента


//Процедура удаления записи из файла
procedure del(a: file of abonent);
label nachalo,ex;//метка начала и конца процедуры
begin
  nachalo:     //метка начала процедуры
  reset(a);
  write('Введите номер:');
  read(nmbr);
  cnt := 0;       //ведем счет записей из файла, чтобы в дальнейшем обратиться к нужной считанной записи и удалить ее
  repeat     //просматривать файл на совпадение номера абонента
    if eof(a) then    //если дошли до конца и не нашли нужного абонента
    begin
      writeln('Абонента с таким номером не существует!');
      write('Найти по другому номеру? (y/n):');
      readln(yn);
      if yn = 'y' then goto nachalo else goto ex;
    end;
    read(a, t);     //чтение записи из файла
    cnt := cnt + 1;   //увеличиваем счетчик записей на один
  until t.number = nmbr;
  writeln('Найденный абонент:');
  writeln(t.number, ' ', t.FIO, ' ', t.adres.street, ' ', t.adres.house, ' ', t.adres.flat, ' ', t.date);
  writeln;
  writeln('Удалить данные об абоненте? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  if yn <> 'y' then goto ex;
  cnt := cnt - 1;
  while not eof(a) do
  begin
    if filesize(a)=cnt+1 then break;
    seek(a, cnt+1); //перевод указателя на следующий элемент
    read(a, t);
    seek(a, cnt);    //перевод указателя на удаляемого абонента
    write(a, t);      //перезапись следующего абонента из файла на место удаляемого
    cnt := cnt + 1;
    seek(a, cnt);   //перевод указателя на следующую за переписанным абонентом
  end;
  seek(a, filesize(a) - 1);   //перевод указателя на последнюю запись в файле
  truncate(a);  //удаление последней записи в файле
  writeln('Данные удалены');
  write('Найти по другому номеру? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  if yn = 'y' then goto nachalo;
  ex:    //метка выхода из процедуры
  close(a);
end;

   //Процедура корректировки записи в файле
procedure edit(a: file of abonent);
label nachalo,ex;//метки начала процедуры и выхода из нее
begin
  reset(a);
  nachalo:     //метка начала процедуры
  write('Введите номер абонента:');
  read(nmbr);
  cnt := 0;       //ведем счет записей из файла, чтобы в дальнейшем обратиться к нужной считанной записи и перезаписать ее
  yn:='n';
  while not eof(a) do
  begin
    read(a, t);     //чтение записи из файла
    cnt:= cnt + 1;   //увеличиваем счетчик записей на один
    if t.number = nmbr then break;
  end;
  if eof(a) then    //если дошли до конца и не нашли нужного абонента
  begin
       writeln('Абонента с таким номером не существует!');
       write('Найти по другому номеру? (y/n):');
       readln(yn);
       if yn = 'y' then goto nachalo else goto ex;
  end;
  cnt := cnt - 1;   //возвращаемся к предыдущей записи, чтобы ее изменить
  writeln('Изменить данные об абоненте? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  readln(yn);
  if yn <> 'y' then goto ex;
  with x do
  begin
    repeat    //просматривать файл на совпадение номера абонента
      write('Номер абонента = ');
      readln(number);
      reset(a);
      while not eof(a) do
      begin
        read(a, t);    //чтение записи из файла
        if t.number = number then
        begin
          writeln('Абонент с таким номером уже существует!');
          break;        //выходим из цикла while и повторяем сначала
        end;
      end;
    until t.number <> number;
    write('ФИО = ');
    readln(FIO);
    write('Улица = ');
    readln(adres.street);
    write('Дом = ');
    readln(adres.house);
    write('Квартира = ');
    readln(adres.flat);
    write('Дата подключения = ');
    readln(date);
    writeln;
  end;
  writeln('Изменить данные об абоненте? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  readln(yn);
  if yn <> 'y' then goto ex;
  seek(a, cnt);
  write(a, x);  //запись переменной в файл
  writeln('Изменения приняты.');
  WriteLn;
  writeln('Найти по другому номеру? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  if yn = 'y' then goto nachalo;
  ex:    //метка выхода из процедуры
  close(a);
end;
//Процедура вывода содержимого файла на экран
procedure find(a: file of abonent);
label nachalo;
begin
     nachalo:
     with x do
     begin
          write('Номер абонента = ');
          readln(number);
          reset(a);
          cnt := 0;   //ведем счет удовлетворяющих запросу записей
          while not eof(a) do
           begin
                read(a, t);    //чтение записи из файла
                if t.number = number then
                begin
                     writeln('Найдено:');
                     writeln(number, ' ', FIO, ' ', adres.street, ' ', adres.house, ' ', adres.flat, ' ', date);
                     cnt := cnt + 1;
                     break;
                end;
           end;
      end;
  if cnt=0 then writeln('Не найдено абонента с таким номером.');
  writeln;
  writeln('Найти по другому номеру? (y/n):');
  readln(yn);
  if yn = 'y' then goto nachalo;
  close(a);
end;



begin
  write('Введите имя файла: ');
  readln(filename);
  assign(abonents, filename);
  repeat
    writeln('1: Вывести содержимое');
    writeln('2: Добавить абонента');
    writeln('3: Удалить абонента');
    writeln('4: Изменить данные абонента');
    writeln('5: Найти по номеру');
    writeln('0: Выход');
    write('Выберите действие: ');
    readln(menu);
    writeln;
    case menu of
      1: show(abonents);
      2: add(abonents);
      3: del(abonents);
      4: edit(abonents);
      5: find(abonents);
    end;
  until menu = 0;
end.
```

Comment: Все эти записи вводятся и выводятся и txt файла

Comment: переименуйте команду `del` на `udalit` . Так же название функции тоже.

Comment: Чем мне это поможет?(

Comment: можно вопрос, зачем вы label используете? вед без этого все можно сделать. и будет лучше

Comment: Главное работает))

Comment: вроде у вас проблма тут. ` cnt := cnt + 1;
    seek(a, cnt);   //перевод указателя на следующую за переписанным абонентом` проверьте дебаггером

Comment: Никогда не используйте имён транслитом. `FIO` и `street` рядом — ужасно. `label nachalo` туда же.

Comment: Если процедуры добавления и вывода не доставляют проблем, и ошибка воспроизводится и без них, уберите их из кода. Тому охота читать простыню? Оставьте минимальный пример, воспроизводящий ошибку.

Comment: Знать бы как использовать дебаггер, я ведь только только учусь)

Comment: назовите в чем программу пишите, если turbo pascal то там F7 пошаговое выполнение. Кроме того если вы в цикле делаете удаление и еще и постоянно делаете seek то не проще написать for i=n to filesize(a) do seek(a,i) .... ? И не делать дополнительных левых переходов?

Comment: pascal abc, не помогает пошаговое, не понимаю я( при ошибке он открывает файл PABCsystem.pas

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает из-за того что в процедуре `del` для чтения переменной используется `read(nmbr);` вместо `readln(nmbr);`, поэтому `readln(yn);` считывает пустую строку. Таким образом `readln(menu);` считывает "y" или "n", а это char в то время когда `readln(menu);` ожидает integer.

> #### Процедура Read
>
> Read считывает все символы до (но не включая) следующего маркера конца
>   строки или пока Eof(F) станет равным True. Read не переходит к
>   следующей строке после чтения. Если полученная в результате строка
>   длиннее, чем максимальная длина строковой переменной, то она
>   усекается. После первого Read, каждые последующие вызовы Read будут
>   видеть маркер конца строки и возвращать строку нулевой длины.

[Источник](http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/pascal_Read)